# XCode alert says UPDATING_LOCKED_* on launch

Tags: xcode

This is on OS X Yosemite. It appears when I try launching Xcode.

[image: Screenshot of dialog: UPDATING_LOCKED_TITLE UPDATING_LOCKED_MESSAGE UPDATING_LOCKED_DEFAULT_BUTTON]

There are no updates shown in the App Store and there are no active downloading updates shown, either. Not exactly the pinnacle of Apple's great user experiences.

I hope I don't have to do a clean install…

Comment: A few things missing from your post: How did you install Xcode? Which version of Xcode? When did that dialog start showing up? What did you do before that? What happens after you press that button? Does it go away you do a restart?

Comment: I have Xcode 6.1.1. Prior to this issue I had updated iTunes a few days ago and just used my MBP for email, Office, browsing since then; I haven't tried launching Xcode since I updated iTunes. Nothing happens when I click the alert button. Rebooting doesn't have any effect. The App Store doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Hmm weird. The current Xcode version is 6.4 and should be shown in the App Store.

Comment: Can you update the suggested answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370577/xcode-alert-says-updating-locked-on-launch/31388587#31388587) @JET? A re-download of Xcode or OS X update is unnecessary.

Comment: You should file a bug to Apple: [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot it seems a weird error. I don't think there will be a easy solution for this error. You have to go through the hard way.

1. Update/Install xcode again. If it didn't then
2. Update iTunes and launch/download Xcode again. If it didn't then
3. Update your Mac OS and try the above

P.S: I usually download xcode from here rather than from Appstore( requires Apple ID to login) https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: I didn't want to waste more time on this so I did #1. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This is correct, but all you need to do is halt the update.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me during the installation of iTunes 12.2.1 (1220C173).

I restarted my computer and ended the update, then Xcode opened properly.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me as well. Restarting the computer fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Restart fixed mine too - after restarting, it asked me if I wanted to install some required components, and once that was done it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Opening Xcode from the App Store fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I attempted to download Xcode 6.4 from the AppStore and got this same message AND the AppStore progress indicator was stuck; I couldn't pause the download because the button was grayed out. I rebooted and restarted the download a few times to no avail. But then I decided to wait and let the thing work itself out, and it did. Aparently there is a bug in the AppStore download for Xcode 6.4 that DOES download it (and it took forever in my slow connection) but does not show a progress bar. When I opened the Activity Monitor's Network tab, there it was!